# How to update record in mongoose with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a record in mlab, a remote mongodb database. I am using express, mongoose and nodejs to update a certain record. I also use promises to avoid the callback pyramid.

Api file:

```
router.put('/chairs/:id', function(req, res, next){

  Chair.findByIdAndUpdate({id:req.params.id}, req.body)
    .then(function() {
      Chair.findOne({id:req.params.id})
    })
    .then(function(chair){
      res.send(chair);
    })
    .catch(next);
```

});

I tested the code above using Postman 'x-www-form-urlencoded'. When i try to **UPDATE** just 1 field 'title' and send **PUT REQUEST** , I am prompted with

```
{
    "myError": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ id: '5953532df36d28458af5609f' }\" at path \"_id\" for model \"chair\""
}
```

I want to update a record and get the ID again and print the updated record.

Please help. I am not sure how to properly nest my promises

Comment: `.findByIdAndUpdate()` just takes a "value" and not an "object". Should be`Chair.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,req.body,{ "new": true}).then(chair => res.send(chair))`. Where the `{ "new": true }` obviates the need to do a following `.findOne()` since the "update" returns the modified `chair` anyway.

Comment: Hi Neil, It works! Can you please write the comment above as answer?

Comment: It's a "typo" and I marked for close as such since the behavior of [`findByIdAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) is documented. Take the win and realize that you also learned you do not need an additional request.

Comment: should be `{ new : true }`